# How to add cursor pointer to view via stylesehet in react native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I am new to React Native, been looking for an answer in google but could not find one. How can I add a cursor pointer to my View element with a nested TouchableOpacity element?
I tried to use as property in stylesheet create method but got error that cursor in not a valid style property. 
Thank's in advance for any info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cursor is the mouse pointer, which is associated with the web browser and clicking links.  Since React-Native is for mobile platforms, the typical situation is the user is tapping things with a finger, and so a 'cursor' or 'pointer' indicating the current mouse position is not necessary.  The user just taps on the element.

I suggest using link styling, or button styling to indicate to the user that they can "click" specific text elements.

Comment: React Native can build web apps now, so it's definitely needed. @BloodyMonkey's answer below worked for me though.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

Web is now supported by react native, so just do

```
cursor: 'pointer'
```

Comment: `ViewStyle` does not support the `cursor` property (at least in react-native 0.63.3), do you probably mean to use something like `styled-components`?

Comment: Works for me, building with Expo.

Comment: this did not work with  "react-native": "0.64.1"

Answer (score 5):

For those using typescript

```
<View style={{
      alignItems:'flex-end',
      //@ts-ignore
      cursor:'pointer'
  }} >{text}</View>
```

Comment: Switching off the fire-alarm in case of fire is not a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

use **Link Tag** instead of pointer cursor event to something using css in functional comnponent and calling on onclick event.
in react when user hover to Link tag than it automatically showing cursor event.
you ***dont need to specify cursor:'pointer';***

Comment: This question is about React Native, not React.